# Best way to use Workflow to update multiple custom number fields

Tags: workflow, field-update

I have a custom object that is Master-Detail to Accounts.  What is the cleanest way to use Workflow with Field Updates to update 1 to 28 fields on the Account when they are populated on the custom object?

Would it be 1 workflow rule with 28 field updates?  I assume a formula would be better than a criteria based rule?  Struggling with how to best approach this, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: If the custom object is a detail to Account, then Account can have 0,1,2,... details. Hence, when the workflow executes on detail 2, it will smash the 28 values on Account set by detail 1.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using the new process builder over workflow rules. You can update a record and modify multiple fields in one screen using the values of the record being modified, example: 
[image: Update Records]